# Ошибка при запуске нескольких тестов сразу

Tags: hibernate, junit, spring-data, testng

Есть таблица, которая логируется с помощью hibernate envers. Пишу тест на несколько таких таблиц. Вот содержимое класса одного из тестов.

```
@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class CompanyAuditStorageTest {
    @Autowired
    private CompanyRepository companyRepository;
    @Autowired
    private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;
    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
    @MockBean
    private AuditorAware<String> auditorAware;

    private Company company;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        when(auditorAware.getCurrentAuditor()).thenReturn(Optional.of("user"));

        company = new Company();
        company.setComment("comment");
        company.setName("new Company");
        companyRepository.save(company);
    }

    @Test
    public void historyCorrectlyStoresTest() {
        company.setName("updated company");
        companyRepository.save(company);

        AuditReader auditReader = AuditReaderFactory.get(entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager());
        Company firstRevision = auditReader.find(Company.class, company.getId(), 1);
        assertThat(firstRevision.getName(), is("new Company"));
        assertThat(firstRevision.getChangedAt(), notNullValue());
        assertThat(firstRevision.getChangedBy(), is("user"));

        Company secondRevision = auditReader.find(Company.class, this.company.getId(), 2);

        assertThat(secondRevision.getName(), is("updated company"));
        assertThat(secondRevision.getChangedAt(), notNullValue());
        assertThat(secondRevision.getChangedBy(), is("user"));
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        Long companyId = company.getId();
        jdbcTemplate.execute("delete from companies_event_log where id = " + companyId);
        companyRepository.deleteById(companyId);
    }
}
```

Таких классов 3. Остальные 2 аналогичные этому, только другая таблица, другая сущность и репозитори. Если каждый класс запускать на выполнение по отдельности, то всё работает, тесты зелёные. Стоит запустить сразу все 3 - первый проходит, остальные красные! Как правило, ругается на самую первую проверку в firstRevision - говорит, что NullPointerException. Понимаю, что ошибка связана с тем, что несколько ресурсов используются одновременно при запуске всех тестов...как-то так. Но как исправить?

Comment: @DirtiesContext попробуйте добавить над тестовым классом

Comment: Добавил. Не помогло. Вообще, обычно в @After удаляется всё из таблиц, с которыми в тесте работал и всё функционирует, тесты зеленятся. Но здесь почему-то это не помогает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашёл проблему! При аудите есть таблица - revinfo, с ней объединение по внешнему ключу. И, когда проходят все тесты разом, поле rev автоинкрементится и почему-то не откатывается!!!

Почистить в After её не удастся, т.к. зависимых таблиц слишком много. Поэтому такое решение:

```
@Test
public void historyCorrectlyStoresTest() {
     company.setName("updated company");
     companyRepository.save(company);

     AuditReader auditReader = AuditReaderFactory.get(entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager());

     List<Number> revisionsListIds = auditReader.getRevisions(Company.class, company.getId());

     Company firstRevision = auditReader.find(Company.class, company.getId(), revisionsListIds.get(0));
     assertThat(firstRevision.getName(), is("new Company"));
     assertThat(firstRevision.getChangedAt(), notNullValue());
     assertThat(firstRevision.getChangedBy(), is("user"));

     Company secondRevision = auditReader.find(Company.class, this.company.getId(), revisionsListIds.get(1));

     assertThat(secondRevision.getName(), is("updated company"));
     assertThat(secondRevision.getChangedAt(), notNullValue());
     assertThat(secondRevision.getChangedBy(), is("user"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно пометить тестовый класс как `@Transactional`. В этом случае, каждый тест будет обернут в транзакцию, которой на выхоже сделают rollback. Тогда и `@After` не понадобится.